# Proportional resizing of JFrame

Tags: java, swing, resize, jframe

I'm trying to make a `JFrame` re-sizable in an unusual way: the ratio of width to height of the frame must be constant. I have written this simple code; in this case, the ratio is 1/2:

```
public class Panel extends JFrame {
  public Panel() {
    addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
      @Override
      public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
      System.out.println("Reseized");
      setSize(getSize().width, getSize().width * 2);
    }
  });
}
```

But this frame has problems with repainting, and it works only when the user drags the mouse. When dragging is finished, the right bottom corner of the frame is situated in the point where user released the mouse.

Maybe `componentResized` method is not applicable in this case? So what should I use?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: I tried out this code, and it appears to work.  Of course, I'm running Linux, so maybe that has something to do with it.  It doesn't do anything until I release my mouse.  Then it changes the height to be the right ratio to the width I re-sized it to.

Comment: Maybe you need to add `revalidate()`, after re-sizing the JFrame.

Comment: @Erick Robertson Works for me, too - Windows 7, Java 6, Eclipse Indigo.

Comment: It depend on window manager, which you use. In Win7 I have problems because the frame is being repainted when you are resizing it.

Comment: @Jean-Philippe Pellet please see my edit, but before next suggestion you have to decide about which coordinates for Dimension will be accepted, this.WEIGHT or this.HEIGHT, because resize (in Windows OS) is proportional process, and output could be freeze or flickering on the screen

Answer (score 4):

Window resizing is handled by the OS; you only get updates post facto. So while you can correct the size after the resize, you cannot constrain the ratio while resizing.

Comment: Hmm, this is the answer I was afraid to get… But no one provided a working solution, so it looks like you're right. :-|

Comment: Actually, there is one way to implement such behaviour. I solve this problem by using setUndecorated(true) and custom mouse listener which implements frame resize.

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
((JFrame)e.getTopLevelAncestor()).pack();
```

where e is you component. Let me know if that work

Comment: `ComponentEvent` doesn't have `getTopLevelAncestor()` method.

Comment: @Lampapos as Ashish said, `e` should be your component, not the event ;o)